# Nuxt js - passing object params in dynamic route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using the following link to dynamic routes

```
<nuxt-link :key="$route.fullPath" :to="{ name: 'items-id', params: { parent: { id: item.parent.id, description: item.parent.description } }}">Click me</nuxt-link>
```

So navigating to `/items/` correctly passes the specified params. But if i click another nuxt-link with different params, while being on the `/items/` url then nothing happens. I imagine it's because the url doesn't really change.

What's the best way to "reload" the url with new params?

I've considered using path which would be different for each nuxt-link

```
<nuxt-link :key="$route.fullPath" :to="{ path: '/items/' + item, params: { parent: { id: item.parent.id, description: item.parent.description } }}">Click me</nuxt-link>
```

But this makes the URL ugly as it includes the object ref

Answer (score 1):

Using watch should do it. Just update the variable you want to change according to the value for example if you want to watch for the id variable then set it to a component variable that you will want to be displayed.

```
watch: { 
 id (value) {
  this.VARIABLE = value
 }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but no luck. The parameters in the url don't really change. Basically what i'm looking for is to re-render the page with a different set of params for each nuxt-link

Comment: I think you should paste your code on watch function here. The problem seems to be in the reloading of your data when the route changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just `watch()` the params (probably the id) and reload data when they change:

```
watch: {
  id() {
     // reload your item here
  },
  ...
},
```

Comment: I've tried it but no luck. The parameters in the url don't really change. Basically what i'm looking for is to re-render the page with a different set of params for each nuxt-link

Comment: we are missing information here: if the id is a parameter of the url, and the nuxt-link includes the id, then for sure, the url changes, and you have a different `id` each time, something like /item/1, /item/20, etc... and the `watch()` method of the component will be called when you navigate from item 1 to item 20